# QGraphicsLayout - Unexpected Extra Spacing Between Items

Tags: qt, layout, user-interface, pyqt

I am using **QGraphics Framework** to write some prototypes. I got in trouble on simulating regular layouting.

There is a large spacing between these two widgets, but I set all the possible spacing to 0 already. For a note, I'm using *Awesome* Windows Manager so that there isn't any border around the window.

[image: Simple Prototype with unwanted extra space]

Here is my code (Sorry, it should be shorter):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt


class PixmapLayoutItem(QtGui.QGraphicsLayoutItem):

    def __init__(self, image, parent=None):
        super(PixmapLayoutItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmapItem = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.pixmapItem.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image))
        self.setGraphicsItem(self.pixmapItem)
        print(self.pixmapItem.boundingRect().size(),
              self.pixmapItem.pixmap().size())

    def sizeHint(self, which, constraint=QtCore.QSizeF()):
        return self.pixmapItem.boundingRect().size()

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        self.pixmapItem.setPos(rect.topLeft())


class TextLayoutItem(QtGui.QGraphicsLayoutItem):

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(TextLayoutItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textItem = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.textItem.setHtml(text)
        self.setGraphicsItem(self.textItem)
        print(self.textItem.boundingRect().size())

    def sizeHint(self, which, constraint=QtCore.QSizeF()):
        return self.textItem.boundingRect().size()

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        self.textItem.setPos(rect.topLeft())


class MainWindow(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout()
        mainLayout.setSpacing(0)

        avatar = self._avatar()
        mainLayout.addItem(avatar)
        mainLayout.setAlignment(avatar, Qt.AlignCenter)

        text = self._text()
        mainLayout.addItem(text)
        mainLayout.setAlignment(text, Qt.AlignCenter)

        mainWidget = QtGui.QGraphicsWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)

        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        scene.addItem(mainWidget)
        self.setScene(scene)

    @staticmethod
    def _avatar():
        pixmap = PixmapLayoutItem("./avatar.jpg")
        text = TextLayoutItem("Hello, world!")

        avatarLayout = QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout()
        avatarLayout.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        avatarLayout.setSpacing(0)

        avatarLayout.addItem(pixmap)
        avatarLayout.setAlignment(pixmap, Qt.AlignCenter)

        avatarLayout.addItem(text)
        avatarLayout.setAlignment(text, Qt.AlignCenter)

        avatarWidget = QtGui.QGraphicsWidget()
        avatarWidget.setWindowFrameMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        avatarWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        avatarWidget.setLayout(avatarLayout)

        return avatarWidget

    @staticmethod
    def _text():
        text = TextLayoutItem("UNIX - Where is a shell, where is a way.")
        return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    App.exec()
```

I don't know what is the root of the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but this could be some layout stretch issue. Try changing the [scene's rect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) to a smaller one and see if that decreases the size of the gap.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? *Unexpected Extra Spacing* means the space between the `avatarWidget` and the text.

Comment: Yes we are. But never mind, I tried to make something similar, but by skipping the `QGraphicsLayoutItem`s and using `QGraphicsWidget`s instead and it worked for me. `QGraphicsLayout::setContentsMargins` is the only function i had to use to remove the gaps.

Comment: It not works for me :(

Comment: You can try doing what i did. Skip `QGraphicsLayoutItem`s and use `QGraphicsWidget` containing `QLabels` and see if it that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line in `_avatar` function:

```
avatarWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

to

```
avatarLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The spacing will go from this:
[image: this]

to this:

[image: this]

Don't know if that's small enough for you or not, but it loses most of the gap.

**UPDATE**

With a smaller pixmap you will see a gap between the image and the UNIX text because the "Hello world!" text is wider than the pixmap (I highlighted the avatar widget border in black):
[image]

Making the text shorter will make the avatar widget smaller and loses the apparent gap:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for figuring out it :)

Comment: Oops. It only works when the image is small enough :( Try this one: http://blog001.oss.aliyuncs.com/avatar.jpg

Comment: If the image is smaller than the text under it then it'll make the entire widget wider. And this will appear as an extra gap between the image and the "Unix .." text. I've updated my answer with some pictures.